# Twig. Объект из контроллера

Tags: symfony, twig

Есть базовый шаблон twig, от которого будут наследоваться другие.
В данном шаблоне (и как следствие на каждой странице) должны будут отображаться значения объекта, полученного из контроллера.

В twig можно получить значение из метода контроллера **{{render(controller(...))}}**, но так можно только отобразить на странице.

Мне нужно как-то получить объект чтобы потом его перебрать в цикле.
Как это можно лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На stackoverflow нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792059/how-to-include-a-reusable-widget-in-symfony-twig) где 3 способа это сделать:

1. Контроллер, который рендерит сгенерированный готовый html код, где все данные уже перебраны, потом  **{{render(controller(...))}}**
2. Сервис
3. Виджет Twig.

Остановится решил на третьем способе:
**Виджет - меню с категориями и подкатегориями**
Класс виджета:

```
// src\AppBundle\Twig\MenuCategoryWidgetExtension.php

    namespace AppBundle\Twig;

    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

    /**
    * MenuCategoryWidgetExtension
    */
    class MenuCategoryWidgetExtension extends \Twig_Extension
    {
        protected $container;

        function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
        {
            $this->container = $container;
        }

        public function getFunctions()
        {
            return array (
                new \Twig_SimpleFunction (
                    'categories',
                    array($this, 'getMenuCategory')
                )
            );
        }

        public function getMenuCategory()
        {
            $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager ();
            $category = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->getCategoryList();
            return $category;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'WidgetExtension';
        }
    }
```

Настройка сервиса с меткой "twig.extension"

```
// src\AppBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

services:

    app.twig.menu_category_widget_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\MenuCategoryWidgetExtension
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags: 
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

В шаблоне Twig:

```
{% set categories = categories() %}
{% for key, category in categories %}
....
```

И далее, данные можно вставлять в html теги

Также, поскольку этот виджет будет использоваться на каждой странице, чтобы каждый раз не делать один и тот же запрос к БД, я настроил кэширование

```
 // app\config\config.yml
.....
    orm:
            query_cache_driver: apc
            metadata_cache_driver: apc
            result_cache_driver: apc



 // src\AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository.php
     .....
    $query = $qb->getQuery()
                ->useQueryCache(true)
                ->useResultCache(true, 1200, 'category_cache')
```

где 1200 - время хранения кэша в секундах.